# C++ Умный указатель

Tags: c++, visual-c++, указатели, smart-pointer

Всем привет. В общем дали мне задание, связанное с сортировкой методом шейкере используя пользовательские типы fraction и data. Их я конечно же реализовал. Так же нужно использовать библиотеку(заголовочный файл) random и использовать умные указатели. Заголовочный файл random я применил и все работает отлично, но вот не знаю я куда применить умный указатель. Начал я читать документацию по нему узнал, что можно применить их к массиву, но примеров нормальных я так и не нашел. Как мне их применить в код? Буду рад ответу. Заранее благодарен.

Вот мой код:

```
 //
//  main.cpp
//  Template_Example
//
//  Created by Lado on 15/12/17.
//  Copyright © 2017 Lado. All rights reserved.
//

#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <utility>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
#include <functional>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy
#include <memory>
#include <random>

using namespace std;

template<typename F>
class data
{
   public:
   inline F dataa(F x)
   {
       F result;
       result = x;
       return result;
   }
   inline F datas(int &size)
   {
       int n = 10;
       size = n;
       F *array = new F[size];
       //TODO:using library random
       random_device rd;  //Will be used to obtain a seed for the random number engine
       mt19937 gen(rd()); //Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
       uniform_int_distribution<> dis(1, 40);
       for(int i = 0; i < size; ++i)
       {
           //rand numbers decimal
           //array[i] = rand()%100+1;
           array[i] = dis(gen);
       }
       return *array;
    }
 };

 int GreatestCommonDivisor(int m,int n) //Наибольший общий делитель
 {
   int r;
   do
   {
       r = m % n;
       m = n;
       n = r;
   } while ( r != 0 );
   return m;
}

template<class T1, class T2>
class Fraction{
private:
   T1 fenzi; T2 fenmu;                            //чеслитель и знаминатель
public:
   Fraction(){}
   ~Fraction(){}
   Fraction(T1 fenzi,T2 fenmu);
   double sever(T1 zi, T2 mu);
   double *maker();
   //friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& out,const Fraction& fra);//i/O must use a heavy overload
   //friend istream& operator>>(istream& in,const Fraction& fra);
   void setValue(T2 mu,T1 zi);
};
template<class T1, class T2>
Fraction<T1, T2>::Fraction(T1 zi,T2 mu):fenzi(zi),fenmu(mu){

   if(mu==0)
   {
       cout << "Error";
       exit(1);
   }
}

template<class T1, class T2>
void Fraction<T1, T2>::setValue(T2 mu,T1 zi){
   fenmu=mu;
   fenzi=zi;
}
template<class T1, class T2>
double Fraction<T1, T2>::sever(T1 zi, T2 mu)
{
   fenzi = zi;
   fenmu = mu;
   if(mu == 0)
   {
       cout << "Error";
       exit(1);
   }

   //cout << fenzi << " " << fenmu;
   return (fenzi/fenmu);
}
template<class T1, class T2>
double* Fraction<T1, T2>::maker()
{
   int n = 10;
   //size_out = n;
   T1 *arr = new T1[n];

   random_device rd;  
   mt19937 gen(rd()); 
   uniform_real_distribution<> dis(1.0, 2.0);

   for(int i = 0; i < n; ++i)
   {

       arr[i] = dis(gen);
       //arr[i] = ((double)rand()) / ((double)RAND_MAX) * 10 + 0.5;
   }
   return arr;
}

template<typename Type1, typename NN>
class cocktailSort
{
 public:
    void sort( Type1* arr, NN len)
    {
        bool notSorted = true;
        while( notSorted )
        {
            notSorted = false;
            for( int a = 0; a < len - 1; a++ )
            {
                if( arr[a] > arr[a + 1] )
                {
                    sSwap( arr[a], arr[a + 1] );
                    notSorted = true;
                }
            }

            if( !notSorted ) break;
            notSorted = false;

            for( int a = len - 1; a > 0; a-- )
            {
                if( arr[a - 1] > arr[a] )
                {
                    sSwap( arr[a], arr[a - 1] );
                    notSorted = true;
                }
            }
        }
     }

 private:
 void sSwap( NN& a, NN& b )
 {
     NN t = a;
     a = b; b = t;
 }
};

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
   // insert code here...
   Fraction<double, double> f(2, 3);
   Fraction<double, double> n;
   //int size = 10;
   int sizer;
   //TODO:using smart pointer for arra 1
   double *arr1;
   arr1 = n.maker();

   data <int> d;
   data <double> sw;
   //int sizer;
   //TODO:using smart pointer for arra 2
   double arr2;
   arr2 = sw.datas(sizer);
   double k = d.dataa(3);
   cout << k << endl;

   //output array 1
   cout << "arr1\n";
   for(int i=0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       cout << *(arr1+i) << " ";
   }
   //output array 2
   cout << "\narr2\n";
   for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       cout << (arr2+i) << " ";
   }

   cocktailSort<double, double> cs;

   //copy arr1 and arr2 into one general array
   double *mass = new double[20];
   for(int i =0; i < 10; i++)
   {
       mass[i] = *(arr1+i);
       mass[i + 10]=(arr2+i);
   }
   cout << "\nKKK\n";
   for(int i = 0; i < 20; i++)
   {
       cout << mass[i] << " ";
   }

   //using sort function
   cs.sort(mass, 20);

   cout << endl << "Sorted: " << endl << "========" << endl;
   for( int x = 0; x < 20; x ++ )
   {
       //for( int s = x; s < 20; s++ )
        cout << mass[x] << " ";
   }
   cout << endl;

   return 0;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Например в функции `datas` выделяется массив из `size` элементов `F *array = new F[size];` затем функция возвращает копию первого элемента (почему?), а вся выделенная память утекает. Вообще вся память, которую вы выделяете через `new` утекает. Как раз с этим и призваны бороться умные указатели.

Comment: вообще-то этот `size`  можно убрать и работать без него при этот действительно утекать ничего не будет. Но я не знаю как использовать, многие указатели работают с массивами к примеру shared_ptr или unique_ptr. Какой лучше в моем случае использовать?

Comment: @Lado Даже если без `size`, то память будет утекать. У каждого умного указателя указана область его применения.

Comment: я понял как можно. Я могу написать таким образом `std::shared_ptr<int> sp( new int[10], std::default_delete<int[]>() );` а в цикле использовать это `sp.get()[i] `

Comment: у меня как раз объект будет удаляться не загромождая память